# Joining Command Line Statements

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I essentially need to get a list of file names from a directory from windows command line and take each file name and combine that with another command line statement.

```
D:\Data 
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

combine file with:

```
copy file1.txt file3.txt
copy file2.txt file4.txt
```

---

I know the above might not make sense. I am trying to understand conceptually how to accomplish the task. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This `for` will loop over all files in d:\data and write out something like `copy file1.txt targetname.txt` for each one.  I don't know how you want to form the name of the target file, but I think this may at least answer your question of how to do something with each file in a folder.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%f in ('dir "d:\data" /b /a-d') do (
    set filename=%%f
    echo Do something with !filename!
)
```

Comment: Thanks for  the help. This didn't seem to work for me though. I don't actually want to copy the content of each file. I only really want to copy the file name into the variable and execute another command using the file name. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the sample code.  Now we enable delayed expansion, so that within the `for` loop you can do a `set` to set an environment variable, then refer to it using delayed expansion:  `!filename!`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you have `file1.txt ... file4.txt` in the current directory, try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d /b /on file?.txt') do (
    set "file1=!file2!"
    set "file2=!file3!"
    set "file3=%%~i"
    if not "!file1!"=="" echo copy !file1! !file3!
)
```

The output is:

```
copy file1.txt file3.txt
copy file2.txt file4.txt
```